# Trouble Playing around with Post requests in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, http-post

So in this link is my problem: https://stackabuse.com/get-http-post-body-in-spring/
It contains a tutorial and I started it and I failed immediatly, not understanding why. Probably some small mistake? Any ideas?

So this is the code:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/response")
public class HomeController {

    @PostMapping("/postbody")
    public String postBody(@RequestBody String fullName) {
        return "Hello " + fullName;
    }

    @GetMapping("/right")
    public String returnAnswer(){
        return "Righto";
    }
}
```

when I run my application and try to curl for a response from the post request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "John Smith" "http://localhost:8080/response/postbody"
```

I get a 401 error. And I dont know why. The get request is working though!

I also tried to add some security config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // allow at the top and block
                                                                                         // as you go down
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("administrator")
                .password("bullshit123")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

}
```

But no matter how hard I try, the post request wont work... the get request is fine though. I oversaw something smallish right?

Answer (score 0):

O my...

So this is the reason. Udpate the bean in SecuirtyConfig like so:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // allow at the top and block
                                                                                         // as you go down
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(csrf -> {
                    csrf.disable();
                })
                .build();
    }
```

csrf is enabled by default and will block post requests when you are testing locally.

What I wonder about: I could not see anything in the logs about this. Anyone have tips how to see stuff like that in the logs?